# Retrieve a record from a function

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want a  function to retrieve the information from table employees, then populate these into the record, return the record to the invoker.  In the block, call F6 with ID (114), and print the information received via the function call.

```
 DECLARE
  TYPE empdetail IS RECORD (
    dept_id NUMBER,
    salary  NUMBER,
    first_name VARCHAR2(20),
    last_name VARCHAR2(25));

  FUNCTION hw2(emp_id IN NUMBER) RETURN empdetail
  IS

    rec1 empdetail;
    avg_sal employees.salary%TYPE;
   BEGIN

   select department_id, salary, first_name, last_name INTO rec1 
   from employees 
   where employee_id = emp_id; 
   avg_sal := salary / 1;

    return avg_Sal;
end hw2;
/
  BEGIN

  emp_no employees.employee_id%TYPE : = 114;
  emp_details := f6(emp_no);

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
    'employee details are: ' ||
    emp_details.emp_id || ', '  ||
    emp_details.dept_id || ', '||
    emp_details.salary || ', ' ||
    emp_details.first_name || ', ' ||
    emp_details.last_name); 
END;
/
```

This gives error:

> ORA-06550: line 22, column 0:
>      PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:
>      begin function pragma procedure
>      06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
>      *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
>      *Action:

Comment: A private function - HW2() in your code - is **part of the declaration** of the wider program. You have a program terminating `/`  after the function declaration, which is wrong. It makes the compiler think your whole program has finished, when actually it's just the declaration section.

Comment: Yes, so i removed the / and still getting that same error

Comment: Well you also have a variable declaration `emp_no employees.employee_id%TYPE : = 114;`  after the BEGIN of the main program. You need to declare your variables in the DECLARE section, and **before** any private program unit.

Comment: And to avert the next syntax error, you have named the function `HW2()` but your program references something called `F6()`. Is F6() an existing standalone function? If so, why bother defining HW2()?

Comment: yeah i'm so sorry but because my function was itself giving error i did not try running the calling function part that is the below part.

Answer (score 0):

I think your function can be a lot more simple. 
 
You can make your function to fetch the data from the table, and store it into a record. Then return the complete record. And print out the data from each column. 
Maybe this will give you an idea:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION hw2(emp_id IN NUMBER)
RETURN Employees%ROWTYPE
IS
        CURSOR cEmployee IS
               SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE Id = emp_id;

        rEmployee cEmployee%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
        OPEN cEmployee;
        FETCH cEmployee INTO rEmployee;
        CLOSE cEmployee;

    RETURN rEmployee;
END;
/

DECLARE
    rEmployee Employees%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    rEmployee := hw2(emp_id => 1);

    -- Print data
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Name:' || rEmployee.Name);
END;
/
```